# Displaying SQL data in 3 divs per line

Tags: php, sql, html

I am trying to create a display loop of my sql data and have it display within a div and a max of 3 divs per line.

It works for the first line and then the divs break out and starts showing up on left of screen outside the main container.

Here is the link to see it live : http://avmor.com/avmor2014/media_videos_facility.php

Here is my code :

```
<?php

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$id=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
$title=mysql_result($result,$i,"title_en");
$desc=mysql_result($result,$i,"desc_en");
$link=mysql_result($result,$i,"link_en");

?>

<!-- DIV box here -->

<?php
$i++;
 }
?>
```

How can i create a display the loop of mysql data ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.
 I have added the div as comment as the code was not displaying correctly.

```
 <?php

    $i=0;
    while ($i < $num) {
    $id=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
    $title=mysql_result($result,$i,"title_en");
    $desc=mysql_result($result,$i,"desc_en");
    $link=mysql_result($result,$i,"link_en");

      if($i == 0){
?>

      <!-- div class="box big_box" -->
      <!-- DIV box here -->

<?php

     }
    else if($i > 0 && $i%3 ==0){
?>
    <!--/div -->
   <!-- div class="box big_box" -->

    <!-- DIV box here -->


<?php

     }
    else
    {
?>  
    <!-- DIV box here -->
<?php
    }
    $i++;
     }
?>   
    <!-- Close the last box>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve that by using css

```
div.product {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
```